# Get last monday in month in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is there a way that I get the last monday in the month with moment.js?

I know I can get the end of the month with:

`moment().endOf('month')`

But how about the last monday?

Comment: Maybe `moment().endOf('month').startOf('week').add('days',1)`? Adding the day because moment startof week is sunday.

Comment: @A1rPun That's returning `Mon Sep 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200`

Comment: Just a friendly reminder to accept the answer if it solves your problem.  :-)

Comment: this causes problems if the day is Sunday.

Comment: I'd chose vinjenzo's answer. The simplest way of getting last monday is to use `moment().startOf("isoWeek")`. Beware that if `moment()` is monday already, you'll not go back one week. If you need that, just subtract a day: `moment().add(-1, "day").startOf("isoWeek")`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you get always monday with [isoweek](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/):

```
moment().endOf('month').startOf('isoWeek')
```

Comment: not sure why this would be deleted given it's the best answer and describes the solution just fine.

Comment: This solution has a bug if the last day of the month is on a Sunday.  For example, try `moment('2020-05-01').endOf('month').startOf('isoweek')`

Comment: @c1moore just tried that line of yours and it worked :/

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  Not sure what I was looking at when I ran it last time.

Comment: `isoWeek` should be written in camel case.

Answer (score 16):

You're almost there.  You just need to add a simple loop to step backward day-by-day until you find a Monday:

```
result = moment().endOf('month');
while (result.day() !== 1) {
    result.subtract(1, 'day');
}
return result;
```

Comment: I can't believe that moment.js is missing something so simple — if I wanted to write loops I could have!

Answer (score 1):

```
moment().endOf('month').day('Monday')
```

Comment: This does not work if the months last day is a sunday. You get the "Monday" of the week. So the Monday in that week would be the next month.

Comment: you need only to check if this day exceeds the selected month and then subtract 7days ;-) then this solution is perfectly fine.

Answer (score -2):

I made a [dropin](https://gist.github.com/penne12/ae44799b7e94ce08753a) for this, once you install/add it, so you can do:

```
moment().endOf('month').subtract(1,'w').nextDay(1)
```

That code gets the end of the month, minus 1 week, and then the next Monday.

To simplify this, you could do:

```
days = moment().allDays(1) //=> mondays in the month
days[days.length - 1] //=> last monday
```

Which gets all the Mondays in the month, and then selects the first one.

You could simplify it further like this:

```
moment().allDays(1).pop()
```

But this removes the Monday from the list - but if you aren't using the list (as in the example above), it shouldn't matter. If it does, you might want this:

```
moment().allDays(1).last()
```

But it requires a pollyfill:

```
if (!Array.prototype.last){
    Array.prototype.last = function(){
        return this[this.length - 1];
    };
};
```