# Is there a way that I can get the (first Sunday in October – first Sunday in April) with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I know that I can use this for the start of the month moment().startOf('month') but I need the first Sunday of the month.

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126829/get-last-monday-in-month-in-moment-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```js
function getFirstWeekDay(dateString, dayOfWeek) {
    var date = moment(dateString, "YYYY-MM-DD");

    var day = date.day();
    var diffDays = 0;

    if (day > dayOfWeek) {
      diffDays = 7 - (day - dayOfWeek);
    } else {
      diffDays = dayOfWeek - day
    }

    console.log(date.add(diffDays, 'day').format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

  }
  //Pass in the first of a given calendar month and the day weekday
getFirstWeekDay("2016-10-01", 0);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this seems to be giving the incorrect value, should be 2016-10-02. First Sunday of October

Comment: My bad, earlier it is First Friday (5) being set as dayOfWeek. Corrected the code. it should be fine now.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way that I can use momentjs to set the date dynamically?

Comment: moment() => gives you todays date.

Comment: yes but I was thinking if I could use it to set the date for the first Sunday of October dynamically?

Comment: You need to pass in the year and month anyways, because they are the inputs. In the above code, if we just return date after .add , it is an moment Date object, with the first Sunday of October 2016

Answer (score 1):

Please check this Code.

```
var d = new Date();
var first_week = d.getDate();
var the_day = d.getDay();

if(first_week <= 7 && the_day == 0)
{
  // It's the first Sunday of the month
  // Do more stuff here
}
```

Comment: Came across this however, it doesn't meet my requirements

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample using js to get the first sunday of any month or year

```js
function firstSunday(month, year) {
    let tempDate = new Date();
    tempDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    // first SUNDAY of april
    tempDate.setMonth(month);
    tempDate.setYear(year);
    tempDate.setDate(1);

    let day = tempDate.getDay();
    let toNextSun = day !== 0 ? 7 - day : 0;
    tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() + toNextSun);
    
    return tempDate.toDateString();
}

console.log("april first sunday" , firstSunday(3 , 2020));
console.log("oct first sunday" , firstSunday(9 , 2020))
```